# .NET Core Angular app running on IIS - NOT IIS Express

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

I have a .NET Core 3.0 Angular app started from the Visual Studio 2019 template. I've done some initial development using IIS Express, but now I'd like to start developing against IIS since that's the web server this app will eventually run on.

I followed the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.0 to set up an IIS profile.

When I switch to the IIS profile and try to debug the app I get the following error:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'
```

I don't have --extract-css in my package.json scripts start and build settings. I've run npm install inside the ClientApp directory (which found 0 vulnerabilities)

How do I set up this app so it runs on IIS? Do I have a misunderstanding about Angular apps? Do they REQUIRE Node as their hosting web server?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install node js on your server.

to deploy the angular site in iis you just need to publish it.

1)open an angular application in visual studio.

2)select a project name and click on publish.

[image]

3)select the folder option and publish it to the target folder.

[image]

4)after publishing the project open iis and select add a new site and select the published folder path and add site bindings.

[image]

Comment: I'm not trying to deploy the app to a server. I'm trying to develop/debug the app against IIS instead of IIS Express.

Comment: @JoshN delete npm folder which is located at C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming, it will be created again. This problem is due to user privileges try to set your site application pool identity to local system or assign a user which has right permission to access the AppData folder.

Comment: there is not npm folder in the location you pointed to

I do see this further down in the error I'm getting though:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'`

Comment: @JoshN did you try to change the application pool identity to local system?

Comment: @JoshN hey did you ever get this resolved? Having the same issue

Comment: I did not. I scrapped the idea of using .NET with Angular and instead used the Angular CLI, Node.js and Visual Studio Code.